# How to log the output

Tags: powershell

guys do you know how to put this on the log whenever i try to log it there's no output
only this variable can capture the result on the logging
**$currentTime**

but this it wont capture on the log i tried converting it to write-host but still not capturing the result of this variable
$processMemoryUsage

here's the output of my code

```
ProcessName        Mem Usage(MB) Mem Usage(%)
-----------        ------------- ------------
OUTLOOK.EXE                 1368        13.68
Memory Compression           628         6.28
Teams.exe                    582         5.82
msedge.exe                   569         5.69
chrome.exe                   548         5.48
```

here's my code

```
$processMemoryUsage = Get-WmiObject WIN32_PROCESS | Sort-Object -Property ws -Descending | Select-Object -first 5 processname, @{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb*1.7)}}, @{Name="Mem Usage(%)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb*1.7)/100}} 
$currentTime = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

            Write-Host "Util is ok of test"   
            $logfilepath="C:\Users\lapasaca\Downloads\Memorylog.txt"
            $logmessage=$currentTime,$processMemoryUsage
            $logmessage >> $logfilepath
```

Comment: Try : $logmessage=string.Join(",",@($currentTime,$test,$processMemoryUsage))

Comment: i got an error string.Join : The term 'string.Join' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting as a result because `$currentTime` is a string and `$processMemoryUsage` is an array of objects so what exactly are you expecting when you do `$logmessage=$currentTime,$processMemoryUsage` ? also `>>` is not the proper operator to export objects.

Comment: Are you wanting to include the date time on every line for the table? Or just at the end of the file?

Comment: yes so i can monitor each application and its utilization by time

Comment: i mean date will be on top then new line then logged the output of the command

Comment: i got the answer it should be like this $test =  $processMemoryUsage | ConvertFrom-String  but i have another problem do you know how i can retain the table ?

Comment: $logmessage= [string]::Join(",",@($currentTime,$test,$processMemoryUsage))

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to use `Out-File` and use the objects you create as input. In this example I changed `Get-WmiObject` to `Get-CimInstance` as it's deprecated. The following will output to a file called `log.txt`.

```
$processMemoryUsage = Get-CimInstance  WIN32_PROCESS | Sort-Object -Property ws -Descending | Select-Object -first 5 processname, @{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb*1.7)}}, @{Name="Mem Usage(%)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb*1.7)/100}}
 
$currentTime = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"


Write-Output "Util is ok of test"   
Out-File -FilePath "log.txt" -InputObject $currentTime -Append
Out-File -FilePath "log.txt" -InputObject $processMemoryUsage -Append
```

The example output in the created log.txt file.

```
02-Oct-2023 23:13:58

ProcessName Mem Usage(MB) Mem Usage(%)
----------- ------------- ------------
firefox.exe       1184.00        11.84
firefox.exe        966.00         9.66
firefox.exe        643.00         6.43
chrome.exe         607.00         6.07
firefox.exe        569.00         5.69
```

Comment: thank you very much sir this is perfect.

Comment: @VidaVida you're welcome! Glad it worked for you.